# Lower bound for $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a RV and $\mu,\sigma^2$ be its average and variance, respectively. How can I show

$$\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma\right) \geq \frac{k^2 - 1}{k^2}$$

for some $k >1$. Had it been $\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \geq k \sigma \right)$, maybe I would have used Chebyshev's inequality somehow. Or can I modify the latter to reach this conclusion? I don't see it

Comment: $\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma\right) \geq \frac{k^2 - 1}{k^2}$ iff $1-\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma\right) \leq 1-\frac{k^2 - 1}{k^2}$ simplifies to $\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| > k \sigma\right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ so isn't this just chebyshev's inequality like you mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma\right) = 1- \mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \geq k \sigma\right). $$

On the other hand, by Chebyshev's inequality we have
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \geq k \sigma\right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}, $$

putting all togheter:

$$ \mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu| \leq k \sigma\right) \geq 1- \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{k^2-1}{k^2}.$$

PD: In Chebyshev's inequality we have a $\leq$ inequality, but in our equiation we have $- \mathbb{P}(\cdots)$ so the inequality change to $\geq$.